# Android development log

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-log

My app is currently giving me out of memory exception and the log is something like this:

Non - rooted Nexus S phone
[image]

Rooted Samsung note 3 phone
[image]

Now my question is on **rooted phone** I can see extra information like "Failed to allocate xxxx byte allocation with xxx free bytes" etc. But on **non-root phone** I can't see those lines.

Does anyone know why?
Thanks

Comment: Are you assuming that Samsung and Google both have the same exact underlying codepaths that execute when `resizeImage` is called?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's rooted or not, I can have it show the byte allocation on non rooted devices as well. I think it's just system code dependent since Samsung runs it's own interface flavour of Android (TouchWiz) similarly when you connect some Samsung devices you might see something like `UnsatisfiedLinkError` which stems from TouchWiz

Comment: @UnsatisfiedLinkError  So is there a way that I can show byte allocation on Nexus S phone? This is so that I can know how much the app was trying to allocate and how much byte I had left at the moment of exception.

Comment: @Pedantic Do they not ??